# Error en Flutter pub get

Tags: flutter, dart

Intentando usar firebase_messagig 7.0.3 que es la mas reciente, cuando la agrego ap pubspec.yaml y que se haga el flutter pub get, marca error porque dice que es necesario usar  otra version de firebade_core, la version que requiere la inserto también, pero luego dice que otra paquetería no es compatible, que se pudiera hacer, para saber la compatibilidad de los paquetes, Para usar firebase_messaging 7.0.3 que es la ultima version y es la que se quiere implementar, se debe de usuar firebase_core 0.7.0 para el funcionamiento de FCM,  A continuacion se muestra el pubspec de los paquetes a utilizar

```
   name: app
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  table_calendar: ^2.2.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+1
  gesture_zoom_box: ^0.0.2
  url_launcher: ^5.4.1
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.27
  google_fonts: ^0.3.9
  data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
  image_downloader: ^0.19.2
  carousel_slider: ^2.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  pdf_viewer_plugin: ^1.0.0+2
  path_provider: ^1.6.1
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  pdf: ^1.5.0
  intl: ^0.16.1
  photo_view: ^0.9.2
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  #firebase_database: ^3.1.1
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.5
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12
  flutter_local_notifications: ^3.0.1
  flutter_app_badger: ^1.1.2
  flutter_widgets: ^0.1.12
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.6
  firebase: ^7.2.1
  flutter_email_sender: ^2.2.2
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6
  flutter_holo_date_picker: ^0.1.2+4
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.4.0
  flutter_open_whatsapp: ^0.1.2
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.8
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Seguramente otros paquetes usan otra version de firebase_core, no es necesario que agregues firebase_core, pero revisa que otros packages de firebase estás usando, si actualizas uno, debes actualizar todos, agrega tu pubspec a tu pregunta

Comment: @diegoveloper  Para usar firebase_messaging se tiene que tener firebase_core 0.7.0, pero no es compatible con las demas

Comment: actualiza los demás packages de firebase para que sean compatibles todos

Comment: @diegoveloper ,solo los de firebase? Como, fitebase_core, firebase_analytics. Los actualizo todos a la última versión?

Comment: así es , porque si actualizas solo uno, ese dependerá de una versión del core más estable y los otros no, ahí el conflicto

Comment: @diegoveloper  Gracias, una pregunta. Una vez que los paquetes pubspec.yaml se han actualizado a la nueva versión, el código marca un error, en firestore ¿qué se puede hacer para corregir estos errores?

Answer (score 0):

A mí me pasó así con firebase_messaging

Si lo actualizas tendrás que actualizar el Core y por ende los demás productos que dependan de él (Core)

practicamente tendrías que actualizar todas las librerías de firebase o su gran mayoría.

Por cierto, para los mensajes en segundo plano tuve que usar la versión dev, ya que la actual 7.0.3 no está funcionando.

Te dejo el enlace de las versiones

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/versions

Comment: antes usaba firebase_messaging 6.0.8 pero dejo de funcionar. Entonces podría usar 6.0.15 es la más reciente de versión dev

Comment: Yo usé la versión **8.0.0-dev.14**

actualmente la más reciente es **9.0.0-1.0.nullsafety.2**

Comment: ,y fue necesario la creación del archivo Applicattion.java y luego llamarlo para setRegistrant?

Comment: Sí, es necesario

Comment: Muy bien, Gracias

Comment: @ Fernando Luis Martínez Se han actualizado los paquetes y ya estan listas, pero despues de pub get packages marca error en el codigo, los paquetes si  son comatibles ahora,pero existe esos errores en el codigo con firebase, usando firebase_messaging 6.0.8 no

Comment: Se han actualizado los paquetes y ya estan listas, pero despues de pub get packages marca error en el codigo, los paquetes si son comatibles ahora,pero existe esos errores en el codigo con firebase, usando firebase_messaging 6.0.8 no